# ASP.NET Core MVC (.NET framework) Bower packages marked as "Extraneous"

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, bower

I was trying to add “jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js” to my ASP.NET Core MVC (.NET framework) application.

When trying to do it using “Manage Bower Packages” and type “unobtrusive” within the search field I couldn’t find any “Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax” package reference. Then I decided to use the command prompt.

I typed:  bower install Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax

The folder “Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax” was added and the .bower.json, bower.json, jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js and the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js were added as well. And if used within the code it works fine.

But when running "bower list" from the command prompt I got the Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax reference marked as extraneous, same happened within the Visual Studio 2015 Dependencies/Bower. And it is not showing within the “Manage Bower Packages” installed packages.

When I run: "bower search jquery.unobtrusive" the result is a list

jquery.unobtrusive-ajax https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive.git

Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax https://github.com/whyleee/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax.git

Streampoint.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax https://github.com/StreampointSolutions/jquery-sps-ajax-unobtrusive.git

Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation https://github.com/whyleee/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation.git

But whatever I use bower install with  “jquery.unobtrusive-ajax” or  “Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax”. I always get the package installed as “extraneous”.

I checked the bower.json and .bower.json files and found nothing out of the ordinary. Can I get some help on understanding why those packages are marked as “extraneous” by bower?

Answer (score 1):

When using "bower install  Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" the bower.json file isn't updated, so I used the **--save** switch:

**bower install  Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax --save**

The bower.json file is updated and the "extraneous" marked disappeared.